# Not able to compile ... Command not started

Tags: errors, compiling

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\chapter{X}
\include{X}

\end{document}
```

It's not compiling at all. Giving me an error saying - pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex

I saw a similar question about this on the site. It did not help me. Please offer some advice.

If it helps, I didn't exactly download TexMaker and MikTex on my current laptop. I simply transferred MikTex and TexMaker from my old laptop to a external hard disk and then transferred it into my current laptop. Both are installed in the "Program Files" folder of the C drive. The LaTex documents are stored in the F drive (which k fragmented).
Please let me know what to configure in the configures dialogue box if that's causing the error.

Thanks.

Comment: This should compile, apart from a warning about the missing `X.tex` file (at least for me

Comment: @ChristianHupfer it isn't for me. Please help. What should I configure in the configure dialogue box ?"

Comment: Sorry, I don't use MikTeX etc on Windows

Comment: What happens if you open a command prompt and enter `pdflatex`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for your problem is a Windows reason:  you can not copy an installed program from computer A to computer B.  That can be possible with UNIX, but not with Windows.

Windows needs to install several files into a special system drive.  Theese files are missing when you did your copy.

So please delete all this files, download the MiKTeX installer you need (I suggest to install the complete MiKTeX) from the MiKTeX homepage, install MiKTeX and run afterwards (you have to do that, do not forget it!) the MiKTeX package manager to be sure all installed packages are up to date.

Then download the installer for your editor and install it.

Then you will be able to compile your code ...

Comment: Can I copy these special system drive files too ?

Comment: Thanks. I installed and installed it again and it's compiling now. Can you tell me what to do in the font encoding section ? It's set to UTF-8 but some tutorials recommend ISO-8859-1.